# Why is DSE shark trying to connect to localhost?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax

Suddenly when I am running running `dse shark` queries it is trying to connect to `localhost:9160`. I have no idea why. None of my Cassandra instances are listening on `localhost`, but on their public IP adresses.

Why could this be?

```
shark> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;
15/01/16 18:05:55 WARN scheduler.DAGScheduler: Creating new stage failed due to exception - job: 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to server localhost:9160
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ConfigHelper.createConnection(ConfigHelper.java:574)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ConfigHelper.getClientFromAddressList(ConfigHelper.java:545)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ConfigHelper.getClientFromInputAddressList(ConfigHelper.java:529)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getRangeMap(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:330)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql3.input.HiveCqlInputFormat.getSplits(HiveCqlInputFormat.java:326)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql3.input.HiveCqlInputFormat.getSplits(HiveCqlInputFormat.java:264)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getShuffleMapStage(DAGScheduler.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$visit$1$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:303)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$visit$1$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:300)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$visit$1(DAGScheduler.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$visit$1$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:305)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$visit$1$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:300)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$visit$1(DAGScheduler.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$visit$1$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:305)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$visit$1$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:300)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$visit$1(DAGScheduler.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$visit$1$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:305)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$visit$1$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:300)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$visit$1(DAGScheduler.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getParentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.newStage(DAGScheduler.scala:250)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.processEvent(DAGScheduler.scala:531)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$start$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:190)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to open transport to: localhost:9160
        at com.datastax.bdp.transport.client.TDseClientTransportFactory.openTransport(TDseClientTransportFactory.java:137)
        at com.datastax.bdp.transport.client.TDseClientTransportFactory.openTransport(TDseClientTransportFactory.java:111)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ConfigHelper.createConnection(ConfigHelper.java:569)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)
        at com.datastax.bdp.transport.client.TClientSocketFactory.openSocket(TClientSocketFactory.java:119)
        at com.datastax.bdp.transport.client.TClientSocketFactory.openSocket(TClientSocketFactory.java:99)
        at com.datastax.bdp.transport.client.TDseClientTransportFactory.openTransport(TDseClientTransportFactory.java:168)
        at com.datastax.bdp.transport.client.TDseClientTransportFactory.openTransport(TDseClientTransportFactory.java:120)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)
        ... 72 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to connect to server localhost:9160
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1020)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:888)
        at shark.SharkCliDriver.processCmd(SharkCliDriver.scala:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
        at shark.SharkCliDriver$.main(SharkCliDriver.scala:240)
        at shark.SharkCliDriver.main(SharkCliDriver.scala)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from shark.execution.SparkTask
```

Additional information:

- I have repaired CFS usig `dsetool repaircfs`.
- None of `dsetool jobtracker/sparkmaster/listjt` refers to `localhost`.
- I have executed `dsetool sparkmaster cleanup` hoping that that would fix something.
- I have made a recursive search for `localhost` in `/etc/dse` and have found no relevant matches so far.
- Hypothesis: Is the metastore somehow refering to `localhost` is it possible to recreate a "Cassandra metastore" somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set cassandra.host to your cassandra ip adresses in Shark conf, or both cassandra.connector.host and cassandra.host for old version of DSE.

Comment: `cassandra.host` did the trick. No idea why I didn't have to use that flag previously. Thanks!